# Requests or Urllib - Login in a website, send download request to url, and save as xlsx

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, mechanize, urllib

I am going crazy with the following problem. What I want to do is login into a website, download a file, while saving the download request as an xlsx.

I am pretty sure I need to use the requests librarybut don't seem to know exactly how to do it. This is what I have so far :

```
import requests



# URL Data



login_url = 'https://reporting.integralplatform.com/uaa/login#/'

report_url = 'https://integralplatform.com/home/brand-safety/firewall?period=%5B2016-09-01..2017-02-19%5D&publisher=all&placement=all&deliveryEnvironment=%5Bdesktop%5D&includeCampaign=true&campaigns=52921%3A52919%3A52931%3A52922%3A52933%3A54272%3A52934%3A54370%3A54363%3A54372%3A54362%3A54369%3A54368%3A54366%3A54365%3A54367&includePlacement=true&grouping=placementName&dateGroup=daily'

download_url = 'https://integralplatform.com/reportingservice/api/teams/3236/fw/campaigns/52921%253A52919%253A52931%253A52922%253A52933%253A54272%253A52934/report.xls?period=%5B2016-09-01..2017-02-19%5D&cutoff=250&mediaType=mixed&groups=%5Bcamp%3Apub%3Aplac%3Adaily%5D&tabs=%5Bfirewall%5D&settings=%7B%22Selected%20Report%22%3A%22Firewall%20Activity%22%2C%22Group%20Dates%20By%22%3A%22Day%22%2C%22Report%20By%22%3A%22Campaign%22%2C%22Campaign%22%3A%22%25%25CAMPAIGN_NAMES%25%25%22%2C%22Media%20Partner%22%3A%22All%22%2C%22Placement%22%3A%22Yes%22%2C%22Geo%20Level%22%3A%22Country%22%2C%22Cutoff%22%3A%22250%22%7D'



# Payload



payload = {

    "username" : 'my username'

,

    "password": 'my password',



    "_csrf_uaa": "507be70c-d4ff-4ea7-a3bf-d45cad3faa47",

}



# Authenticate



login = requests.post(login_url, data=payload)



# Download File



download  = requests.post(download_url, data=payload)
```

However, while I look at both login.content and download.content it seems like I fail to even login as the result is :

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en" ng-app="iasLogin">\n<head>\n\n    <meta charset="UTF-8">\n\n    <title>IAS Login</title>\n\n\n    <!-- Start Vendor CSS -->\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ias-app-vendor.min.css">\n    <!-- End Vendor CSS -->\n\n    <!-- Start IAS CSS -->\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ias-app.min.css">\n    <!-- End IAS CSS -->\n\n</head>\n<body>\n\n    <ias-headers></ias-headers>\n\n    <div ui-view></div>\n\n    <!-- Start Vendor JS -->\n    <script src="js/ias-app-vendor.min.js"></script>\n    <!-- End Vendor JS -->\n\n    <!-- Start IAS JS -->\n    <script src="js/ias-app.min.js"></script>\n    <!-- End IAS JS -->\n\n</body>\n</html>'
```

What it seems to me is that I am clearly doing something wrong when it comes to the payload. However, I don't know how to fix it.

To clarify, the difference between report_url and download_url is that download_url is the url I receive when I right click the download button. The parameters are fixed.

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely need to include headers and form data that the page submits along with your current payload.